# Convert decimal to greyscale image in Java

Tags: java, arrays, image

I have a 2D array which contains values from 0-1.0 and my goal is to create an image where each element corresponds to a colour between white and black. Higher the value, the more white and vice versa.

So far I'm come up with the following Java code:

```
           BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(fg.getLengthInFrames(), 32 ,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

           for(int i =0; i < 32; i++) {
                for(int j =0; j < fg.getLengthInFrames(); j++) {
                    colSTI.setRGB(j, i, 0); // wrong
                }
            }
```

Obviously this wont work as it is just a dummy function but say I had an array element, arr[0][5] = 0.85. How would I be able to convert this into a rgb value that is equal to the corresponding colour value?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Sorry completely skipped my mind to state, in Java.

Comment: As for your problem, remember that black is usually RGB(0, 0, 0) and white is RGB(255, 255, 255). How could you make a value between 0 and 1 be between 0 and 255, where 0 corresponds to 0 and 1 corresponds to 255? Then just set RGB to all the same values.

Comment: Going from a number between 0 to 1 to 0 and 255 should be easy, simply multiply by 255 but this won't give me a colour that is between black and white.

Comment: Yes it will, if you set all of red, green and blue as the same value, then you get a gray-scale.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that. The issue might just be the `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` then because when I use that, my colours are either black or white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TYPE_INT_ARGB` image type (a color image supports gray scale no problem). Use

```
colSTI.setRGB(j, i, new Color(gray,gray,gray).getRGB());
```

to set the integer [color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int)) value for the `BufferedImage`, here `gray` is you shade of gray int the range 0 .. 255. If the image is huge, to avoid creating and garbage collecting lots of `Color` objects, you can implement some kind of gray scale to color caching.

This approach supports 255 levels of gray only. You may need more complex approach if more levels are required. If you are representing some measured physical value in your image, I would propose to use color as well for representing different levels. Such false color images are common in science as they allow to see more levels easier.